# GNU coreutils 8.4, split is not having an option to specify starting numeric-suffixes while splitting the file

Tags: linux, split

I am using the Split command on linux and trying to split the file in to n number of files based on number of records, and after splitting each file gets a million records.

The command that I am using is

```
split -a 3 --numeric-suffixes -l 1000000 - 20141113_File.txt.
```

And this command is creates me n files with naming convention 20141113_File.txt.000, 20141113_File.txt.001,...20141113_File.txt.010

What I am looking is the first file should start with 001 not with 001 prefix, like 
20141113_File.txt.001, 20141113_File.txt.002,......20141113_File.txt.011

I am able to achieve the same in 8.2.1 GNU Coreutilities version.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but do you mean 1M with 10lakhs? Also, since we are an international community, maybe you should use proper wording for such things as sizes and numbers. Otherwise, people might start to talk of a "dutzend" or "tojsnt" MB or a stone of problems.

Comment: Check [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension), possibly you will have solution from that question.

Comment: I do agree with you, by doing loop on top of those files and with renaming will work for me. I had got the same thought, but that will be the last option for me, if the command is not supporting I will go with that option. Earlier I am able to achieve the same using the command "split -a 3 -e --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 1000000 - 20141113_File.txt." (in GNU 8.2.1), here numeric-suffixes supports my use case. I am not sure why the same option is not available in GNU 8.4.